# Why was the VC10 unusually prone to reverser-induced buffeting?

Tags: thrust-reverser, vickers-vc10

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC10#Development_and_production), the original (“Standard”) version of the Vickers VC10 had thrust reversers only on the outboard engines, as putting reversers on the inboard engines produced severe tailplane buffeting and attendant fatigue problems.  The larger, heavier Super VC10 had modified and repositioned engine pods in order to resolve this issue, allowing the Super to have reversers on all four engines; despite these changes, [the buffeting from the inboard reversers proved to still be severe enough to necessitate their near-immediate removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC10#Commercial_service_and_sales).

In contrast, the vast majority of jetliners with tail-mounted engines (leaving aside oddities like the [F28](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_F28_Fellowship), which has no thrust reversers at all, and the [Il-62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62), which has four engines, with reversers only on the outboard pair, like the VC10) experience(d) little or no trouble with reverser-induced buffet, even though their engines - like the VC10’s inboard pair - are (or were) located immediately adjacent to the empennage, and, thus, should be just as prone to inducing buffet as the inboards on the VC10.  1-11, DC-9, 727, Tu-154, F100, CRJ900 - all have (or had) tail-mounted engines with thrust reversers, but none experienced the buffeting problems seen with the VC10’s inboard engines.  Why is this?

Comment: I don't think the root cause was ever fully defined. It appears this was one of those "If it hurts, don't do it" situations where they found the buffeting stopped when the inboard engines did not reverse, and they decided finding the workaround was cheaper than working out the full aerodynamic cause and fix.

Comment: Travelling on RAF Transport Command VC10 coming over the N coast of France, the Captain announced 'we're high and fast for landing at Lyneham, so we will reverse the engines, you will feel some buffeting as the rear edge of the wings stall.' So, we did that, sense of braking and shaking and we came into Lyneham for a perfect landing.
Watching 747 pilot on You Tube, he says, no plane reverses its engines until it is on the ground. Evidently not true!

Answer (score 2):

It may just be that other airframes mount their engines with sufficient clearance to avoid the buffeting issues that were seen on the early VC-10's. Ultimately [it only took of a move of 11 inches](http://www.michaelprophet.com/News_articles/News_articles2010/VC10.html) to solve the issue

> ...testing was prolonged **by the need to move each engine pair 11 in (27
>   cm) outboard.** This major redesign was needed to **resolve tail-plane
>   buffeting and fatigue issues due to thrust reverser operation**. The two
>   inboard engines could have thrust reversers installed at last,
>   matching the 707.

So while it may appear in photos that other aircraft have similarly mounted engines you would need to look at actual technical drawings to truly compare mounting distances.

Its also worth noting that there is nothing saying other aircraft do not also see buffeting from their aft mounted thrust reversers, however they may not see enough to [cause *structural* issues as was the case with the VC-10](https://books.google.com/books?id=usBFDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=vc10%20thrust%20reverser%20buffet&source=bl&ots=acNiHUsn0b&sig=ACfU3U2WyaoDTP3ubL0pcjkgXD2BvkIIHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU5s3Hw5PgAhVls1kKHYyDDh0Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=vc10%20thrust%20reverser%20buffet&f=false).

Comment: Except that, even _with_ the relocated engines, they _still_ ended up with enough buffeting that they had to remove the inboard reversers almost immediately.